# Is it possible to make all targets '.PHONY' ? (gmake)

Tags: makefile

I have a `Makefile`, where none of the targets reference files, so if this can be done in some loop it would be 
convenient.

Is there some way to set every target in a makefile as `.PHONY` ?

---

The reason I'm asking this is I never want any files in the same directory as the makefile to conflict with the targets *(where the makefile will automatically associate any target with a directory of file)*.

Comment: What effect/benefit, specifically, from phony targets are you trying to get here? I don't know of a way to do what you want but we might be able to get the same effects/benefits another way.

Comment: @Etan Reisner, clarified in question.

Comment: Do the targets in question have **any** non-phony targets? That is are there **any** targets in the makefile that should **ever** follow normal make rules about prerequisite existence/timestamps/etc.?

Comment: As stated in the question `I never want any files in the same directory as the makefile to conflict with the targets` - so no, there are no targets related to the filesystem.

Comment: I know I was just making extra sure because the solution I was going to suggest was `-B` (as andree did) and that would cause problems if there were.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can ensure targets always build by defining one empty "FORCE" target and have all you're other targets depend on it

```
target1: FORCE
      ./foobar $@
target2: FORCE
      ./dongle $@
FORCE:
```

(as suggested in the [make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Force-Targets.html#Force-Targets))

You can also run "make -B" instead of "make"?

```
`-B'
`--always-make'
     Consider all targets out-of-date.  GNU `make' proceeds to consider
     targets and their prerequisites using the normal algorithms;
     however, all these targets are remade, regardless of the status of
     their prerequisites.
```

Comment: The `-B` argument is fine if make is called from a script, but if you want to have a makefile in a project's root, anyone downloading might forget to pass the `-B` argument even if its documented. in short - a dummy target (which we make sure doesn't match a file name), will ensure predictable behavior for anyone calling make from the command line.